# ELMAH for ASP .NET MVC Windows Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I need to log errors for an asp.net mvc windows application which also uses entity framework and for doing this i thought of using ELMAH.

My App.config file contains the appsettings for providing folderpath and other file related details.

Now when I try to add the configuration (elmah...../elmah) for ELMAH after installing it in my project it throws an exception "Configuration system failed to initialize".

But when I remove that code then it works fine.

Please provide me the solution to log errors for MVC windows application.

And the final question is ELMAH.mvc free to use or not?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="folderpath" value="~PA\FileImport"/
    <add key="XMLFolderPath" value="~\FileImport\XML"/>
    
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="####" connectionString="############"
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <elmah>
..........
  </elmah>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there's a problem with your ELMAH configuration, since ELMAH and EntityFramework normally doesn't interfere with each other. I would recommend you to follow a tutorial like this: [ELMAH Tutorial](http://blog.elmah.io/elmah-tutorial/). There's a ton of tutorials for ELMAH outthere, why a simple google search will find a lot of resources.

If following a tutorial doesn't work, you should probably add some additional information and web.config code in this thread, since figuring out your problem from the amount of information, is almost impossible.